# How to write query result to persistent store

Tags: ignite

I did some query against a cache, and I want to save the query result to a persist store, eg, mysql db.

I would ask what's the recommended way to accomplish this? Is there some code example for reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this data in cache as well, use write-through. Otherwise, just update your DB directly. I don't see how Ignite can participate in this process.

Comment: Sure, thanks @Valentin.Looks I have to iterate over the query result set, and save the entry to the DB.